# Кеширование Wordpress

Tags: кэширование, wordpress

Помогите разобраться, как заставить wordpress кешировать страницы не только для гостей сайта, но и для авторизованных пользователей? Сейчас стоит плагин Hyper cache, он не справляется стакой задачей, может есть готовые решения? Или может как то доделать этот плагин?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/). Очень гибкая штука, почти все настраиваемое.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы подходит